# Custom type is incompatible with mixed

Tags: flowtype

The problem can be demo'd [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAod6oFcB2BjAFwEs4cwo44AKADwC4wBBAJ2YEMBPAHgFsiaApgBMAfAEoGAZwLMiOAOZgA3qjBhgwMADodYIXDCS4PAQQAWc+arDNTWZmQBEZgTHiPUAX3QEOABwEwABULBTAAXmVrIiEpGUsvdBhTMDZWTjAGFnZuEMsRCLAAbSUYhgByFzc4cs8AXQBuTEoqNJyxBqA)

I want to define a function that can take an array of mixed types:

```
function foo(x: Array<mixed>): string {
  // ... do something
}
```

Then I try to call it with an array off some custom object type:

```
type Thing = {
  id: string
}

let array : Array<Thing> = [{id: 'hello'}];

foo(array);
```

... and I get the following error

```
Cannot call `foo` with `array` bound to `x` because `Thing` [1] is incompatible with mixed [2] in array element.`
```

Is there something that I'm not understanding about the `mixed` type. Why can't a use an array of objects as an argument?

Comment: Looks like a bug, I've raised an issue with a simplified example. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6054

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with a mutability of the array argument.  You can use `$ReadOnlyArray` to satisfy the requirement.

```
function foo(x: $ReadOnlyArray<mixed>): string {
  // ... do something
  return "hello";
}

type Thing = {
  id: string
}

let array : Array<Thing> = [{id: 'hello'}];

foo(array);
```

Array's are passed by reference, not by value, so the value contained in the variable `array` can be modified within `foo`.  e.g.

```
x.push(1)
```

`array` would no longer be an array of `Thing` only.  So using $ReadOnlyArray means that `x` is immutable and therefore `array` is safe.